# Using wget on Linux to scan sub-folders for specific files

Tags: linux, wget

Using `wget -r -P Home -A jpg http://example.com` will result me a list of files from that website directory, what i'm searching for is how do i query a search like: `wget -r -P home -A jpg http://example.com/from 65121 to 75121/ file_ 100 to 200.jpg`

Example(s):

```
wget -r -P home -A jpg http://example.com/65122/file_102.jpg
wget -r -P home -A jpg http://example.com/65123/file_103.jpg
wget -r -P home -A jpg http://example.com/65124/file_104.jpg
```

Is it possible to achieve that on a Linux distro?
I'm fairly new to Linux OS, any tips are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a nested for loop and some bash scripting:

```
for i in {65121..75121}; do for j in {100..200}; do wget -r -P home -A jpg "http://example.com/${i}/file_${j}.jpg"; done; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Wget has loop

```
wget -nd -H -p -A file_{100..200}.jpg -e robots=off  http://example.com/{65121..75121}/
```

If there are only file_{100..200}.jpg It's simpler

```
wget -nd -H -p -A jpg -e robots=off  http://example.com/{65121..75121}/
```